# Child theme not working properly

Tags: php, css, child-theme

There's a theme that I want to customise and when I use a child theme in it's most basic form, the main navigation bar disappears, the fonts seem different and there's a few other oddities.

The problem theme is PR Pin (http://wordpress.org/themes/pr-pin).
My child theme literally only has the style.css file containing my child them name, the template and the import of the parent theme's css.

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Custom Theme for sallymustang.com (pr-pin)
 Template:     pr-pin
*/

@import url("../pr-pin/style.css");
```

I don't know why activating the child breaks the parent when there's nothing changed.

Any help?

Comment: "the display of a number of elements breaks" is not much of a trouble ticket.

Comment: updated for you

Comment: Post your `style.css`

Comment: I determined why the main nav was missing - the theme requires a menu to be chosen specifically for that menu location.  The theme change untoggled this setting.

Comment: Now I've added styles to my style.css yet the theme seems to be ignoring them completely.

Comment: It sounds like you may just have a CSS problem.

Comment: Most definitely not.  If you download the theme and try it yourself you will see what I mean.
Most of the CSS is driven by the parent theme's functions file and a bootstrap.min.css which overrides my style.css. 
I'm just gonna choose a different theme.

Comment: Oh... it is one of _those_ themes. Sorry, I don't have the time to download and install every theme that get mentioned here. I hope you understand.